# Cosine Similarity

Tags: java, similarity, trigonometry, tf-idf, dot-product

I calculated tf/idf values of two documents. The following are the tf/idf values:

```
1.txt
0.0
0.5
2.txt
0.0
0.5
```

The documents are like:

```
1.txt = > dog cat
2.txt = > cat elephant
```

*How can I use these values to calculate cosine similarity?*

I know that I should calculate the dot product, then find distance and divide dot product by it. How can I calculate this using my values?

One more question: *Is it important that both documents should have same number of words?*

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for http://mathoverflow.net/ ?

Comment: its an information retrieval task, not something a pure math person would care about

Comment: Please stop recommending mathoverflow.net -- it's for serious mathematical questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
            a * b
sim(a,b) =--------
           |a|*|b|
```

a*b is dot product

some details:

```
def dot(a,b):
  n = length(a)
  sum = 0
  for i in xrange(n):
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
  return sum

def norm(a):
  n = length(a)
  for i in xrange(n):
    sum += a[i] * a[i]
  return math.sqrt(sum)

def cossim(a,b):
  return dot(a,b) / (norm(a) * norm(b))
```

yes. to some extent, a and b must have the same length. but a and b usually have sparse representation, you only need to store non-zero entries and you can calculate norm and dot more fast.

Comment: Thanks, But I am also confused about one more thing. I saw people talking about this over net. I couldn't understand. Should I calculate cosine similarity on tf/idf values OR. Only idf values or only tf values?????
I know php and start learning java. But i am sorry i don't know which lang. code you used here? can you please let me know, i will look that lang. basic syntax. Or if you can use my tf/idf values to calculate cosine similarity, it will show me how to write a function for that...
thanks again for reply!

Comment: @agazerboy the sample is given in python, which should be quite readable. for i in xrange(n) means for (i=0; i<n; i++).

you should calculate on tf-idf values, sometimes you can also use tf.

Answer (score 9):

simple java code implementation:

```
  static double cosine_similarity(Map<String, Double> v1, Map<String, Double> v2) {
            Set<String> both = Sets.newHashSet(v1.keySet());
            both.retainAll(v2.keySet());
            double sclar = 0, norm1 = 0, norm2 = 0;
            for (String k : both) sclar += v1.get(k) * v2.get(k);
            for (String k : v1.keySet()) norm1 += v1.get(k) * v1.get(k);
            for (String k : v2.keySet()) norm2 += v2.get(k) * v2.get(k);
            return sclar / Math.sqrt(norm1 * norm2);
    }
```

Comment: [An anonymous user comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/237603) that this should be `both.retainAll()` not `removeAll` to get the intersection

Answer (score 1):

1) Calculate tf-idf ( Generally better than t-f alone but completely depends on your data set and requirement)

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) ( regarding idf )

> An inverse document frequency factor is incorporated which diminishes
>   the weight of terms that occur very frequently in the document set and
>   increases the weight of terms that occur rarely.

2) No , it is not important that both the documents have same number of words.

3) You can find `tf-idf` or `cosine-similarity` in any language now days by invoking some machine learning library function. I prefer python

Python code to calculate [tf-idf](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) and [cosine-similarity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity) ( using [scikit-learn 0.18.2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) )

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
# example dataset
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

# replace with your method to get data
example_data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all').data

max_features_for_tfidf = 10000
is_idf = True 

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features=max_features_for_tf_idf,
                             min_df=2, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=is_idf)


X_Mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(example_data)

# calculate cosine similarity between samples in X with samples in Y
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(X=X_Mat, Y=X_Mat)
```

4) You might be interested in [truncated Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html)