# similar_text alternative PHP (Is this text contain this text ?)

Tags: php, function

I would like to create a function who return a percentage of similitude between 2 texts extracting, the non-duplicate part in PHP.

Exemple :

**Text 1**

> Paris was founded in the 3rd century BC by a Celtic people called the Parisii, who gave the city its name. By the 12th century, **Paris was the largest city in the western world, a prosperous trading centre, and the home of the University of Paris, one of the first in Europe**. In the 18th century, it was the centre stage for the French Revolution, and became an important centre of finance, commerce, fashion, science, and the arts, a position it still retains today.

**Text 2**

> Paris was the largest city in the western world, a prosperous trading centre, and the home of the University of Paris, one of the first in Europe.

How can I not take into account the non-duplicated text. 
With this exemple I would like to return 100% duplicate.

Comment: what have you tried so far, maybe you should post some of your code (if you have)

Comment: What would you accept as a 90% duplicate?

Comment: If you're searching for __exact__ matches, then strpos(); otherwise do something like str_word_count() for each block of text and look at the intersect between the the two resultant arrays

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325588/text-similarity-algorithm?lq=1 - the question is tagged `java`, but the algorithms mentioned are available in PHP as well.

Comment: @Piskvor I even try the Levenshtein function !

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/TE0Ac)

Comment: there are many distances (with pseudo-code) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures

Comment: if your use case is quite complex maybe a full (natural language) parser (which can find similarities as well based on grammar patterns) is more appropriate (i have such a project but is currently under development)